# How To Figure Out How Many Files and Directories Exist In A File Without Counting Files in Sub-Directories?

Tags: bash, file, directory, thor

I'm currently working on the following problem for my class and I can't seem to figure out how to go about doing this. Everything I look up just leads me astray. Here is the question and thank you very much.

How many files and directories exist within /usr/include on Thor? Don't count the files in sub-directories. Hint: The following command outputs a list of all files and directories under /usr/include:

ls -ld /usr/include/*

Answer (score 2):

The `find` command can take arguments to specify the maximum and minimum depth to search.
Something like this would return the list of all files and directories in the given path

```
$> find /path/to/count/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1
```

If you want the number of results, pipe it into `wc -l`

```
$> find /path/to/count/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | wc -l
```

`-maxdepth 1` means only go layer down from the given path

`-mindepth 1` means go at least 1 layer down from the given path (otherwise the given path is returned)

Comment: Thank you very much